# Why is the graphic not working when the button number 8 is pressed?

Tags: java, swing

I have this code and it works with everything until the bottom middle button is pressed.

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class memory extends JFrame {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(156, 93, 82));
        g.fill3DRect(21, 3, 7, 12, true);
        g.setColor(new Color(156, 23, 134));
        g.fillOval(1, 15, 15, 15);
        g.fillOval(16, 15, 15, 15);
        g.fillOval(31, 15, 15, 15);
        g.fillOval(7, 31, 15, 15);
        g.fillOval(22, 31, 15, 15);
        g.fillOval(16, 47, 15, 15);
    }

    public memory() {

        GridLayout h = new GridLayout(3, 3);
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final JPanel pan = new JPanel(h);
        frame.add(pan);
        //pan=new JPanel(h);
        pan.setBackground(new Color(130, 224, 190));
        setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 28));
        JButton button1 = new JButton();
        pan.add(button1);
        final JLabel label1 = new JLabel("hi");
        label1.setVisible(false);
        pan.add(label1);
        JButton button2 = new JButton();
        pan.add(button2);
        final JLabel label2 = new JLabel("hi");
        label2.setVisible(false);
        pan.add(label2);
        JButton button3 = new JButton();
        pan.add(button3);
        final JLabel label3 = new JLabel("hi");
        label3.setVisible(false);
        pan.add(label3);
        JButton button4 = new JButton();
        pan.add(button4);
        final JLabel label4 = new JLabel("hi");
        label4.setVisible(false);
        pan.add(label4);
        JButton button5 = new JButton();
        pan.add(button5);
        final JLabel label5 = new JLabel("hi");
        label5.setVisible(false);
        pan.add(label5);
        JButton button6 = new JButton();
        pan.add(button6);
        final JLabel label6 = new JLabel("hi");
        label6.setVisible(false);
        pan.add(label6);
        JButton button7 = new JButton();
        pan.add(button7);
        final JLabel label7 = new JLabel("hi");
        label7.setVisible(false);
        pan.add(label7);
        JButton button8 = new JButton();
        pan.add(button8);
        final JLabel label8 = new JLabel("hi");
        label8.setVisible(false);
        pan.add(label8);
        JButton button9 = new JButton();
        pan.add(button9);
        final JButton button10 = new JButton("Exit");
        pan.add(button10);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("memory Game");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(pan, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(button10, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setSize(600, 600);
        setVisible(true);
        final JLabel label9 = new JLabel("hi");
        label9.setVisible(false);
        pan.add(label9);
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                label1.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                label2.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                label3.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                label4.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                label5.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        button6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                label6.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        button7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                label7.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
//this is where I thought it was going to do something if it was pressed.
        button8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                label8.setVisible(true);
                frame.getContentPane().add(new memory());
                setVisible(true);

            }
        }
                );
        button9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                label9.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
                );
        button10.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (button10.getSize() != null) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new memory();
    }

}
```

Comment: 1- There is no `paintComponent` of `JFrame`...

Comment: sorry but how would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

`memory` extends `JFrame`.  Swing won't let you add a window to another window.

You should avoid extending from top level containers (this is just reason) and instead use something like `JPanel`.

This allows you to add the component to whatever container you like

`JFrame` does not have a `paintComponent` method, so it will never be called.  The reason it compiles is that you've called `super.paintComponents` (note the `s` at the end).

Instead, you should, extend from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method and perform you custom painting from there

Comment: How do you override the paintComponent? Sorry i'm really new to this whole thing...

Comment: @user2853125 Start by checking out [Performing custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: ok so I think I fixed it but it is now not opening so what should I do? All I did was change it to extend JPanel and add @Override   on top of this line   'public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {' so what do I do? someone please help

Comment: 1- Make sure you are calling `super.paintComponent` and not `super.paintComponents`.  Create an instance of a `JFrame` and add your `memory` component to it, make this frame visible.  You might like to take a closer look at [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)